# Image in boostrap column isn't the same height as the column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Pretty much tried everything and have been stuck on it for a few hours now, http://www.bootply.com/NkVjGAhr4p I have two images, and the one on the right doesn't fill/stretch out to the bottom of the column (I have used a background to show what is exactly happening) I'd like it so that the image covers the purple and is even with the other image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images aren't cropped to same size. So crop them to equal sizes. I prefer 800x500. Then if you want Image to cover whole div add `{ padding-left: 0 padding-right: 0;}` to your div. Then image will cover whole div.